# Would creatures of the same species evolve into different creatures if they came into contact with the 'black substance' in Prometheus?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

In the movie *Prometheus*, the worm which came into contact with the 'black substance' quickly mutated into a snake-like creature.

What are the odds that other worms of the same species that came into contact with the same 'black substance' would mutate into different creatures? Like for example a lizard-like amphibious creature?

Comment: I like this question - but I'm not sure it's answerable from the source material available

Answer (score 1):

No.  [Here](https://www.ign.com/wikis/prometheus/The_Black_Substance) is an explanation which was gleaned from Ridley Scott's comments.  According to the explanation given, the black goo is a catalyst for evolution.  Contacting the substance appears to cause living things to radically and quickly evolve into hostile life forms.  Given that it causes living things to evolve, I think we can draw the conclusion that they would evolve into creatures from their same biological family:  Worms wouldn't evolve into cats.

Comment: This... is not really how evolution works. By this logic, everybody in existence would be the same kind of creature, because we all evolved. That's the problem with how movies try to show evolution, you can really "evolve" in a vacuum.