# In the movie Prometheus, what makes Fifield turn into a Monsterous Psychopath?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

We see David poison Charlie with the black ooze, but Charlie doesn't go crazy and try to kill everyone, and the other scientist appears to just be killed by the freaky snake thing inside of the dome structure, so my question is what exactly happens to Fifield that turns him into a Zombified homicidal maniac?

Is there currently an explanation for this anywhere?

Comment: related http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38360/would-creatures-of-the-same-species-evolve-into-different-creatures-if-they-came